# Is there a way to access Document Setting by code to uncheck the adaptivity box?

Tags: vb.net, autodesk

I am using vb net and macros to create a file in autodesk inventor 2014, placing and constraining it between two other objects in an assembly file. The part is already adaptive and I also set it to be adaptive in the assembly. This is where my problem lies. Sometimes the part file won't be able to become adaptive. I have found that is because of the "adaptively used in an assembly" box. For some reason it becomes checked when the part is created. Is there a command in vb.net to access the document settings and uncheck the "adaptively used in an assembly" box before i set it to adaptive in the assembly?

Thank you very much for reading my question, and i hope to hear your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Parts and assemblies that are placed in another assembly can only be adaptive in one assembly.  It sounds like the part you are placing has been set to adaptive in an assembly other than the assembly you are trying to make it adaptive in (sorry if that sounds confusing).  If your part is referenced in another assembly, and is adaptive there, it can't be adaptive anywhere else.  You can change the adaptivity if this is not the case.  You need to get a reference to an occurrence of the part in the assembly document:

```
occurrenceOfYourPart.Adaptive = true;
```